# MySQL denied user from SELECT

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have a MySQL database running on AWS RDS. I also have a process which runs a `SELECT` query from a server called `SOME_EC2`.

> "SELECT command denied to user 'myuser'@'SOME_EC2_HOSTNAME' for
>   table 'mytable'") [SQL: u'SELECT mydb.mytable.my_column AS my_column
>   FROM mydb.mytable']

I can connect to the database using `mysql` client and then run the `SELECT` query from a separate server (more on this later) and also from my laptop using the following command.

```
mysql -u myuser -pMY_PASSWORD -h MY_DB_HOSTNAME mydb
```

But I get access denied if I use this command:

```
mysql -u myuser@'SOME_EC2_HOSTNAME' -pMY_PASSWORD -h MY_DB_HOSTNAME mydb

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser@SOME_EC2_HOSTNAME'@'my_laptop'
(using password: YES)
```

Is this valid? Perhaps grants limited hosts.

So here is the output of `SHOW GRANTS`:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR myuser;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for myuser@%                                                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mydb'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret>                   |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP ON `mydb`.* TO 'mydb'@'%' |
| GRANT SELECT ON `anotherdb`.`another_table` TO 'mydb'@'%'                           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Okay, so it should allow me to run `SELECT` from any host.

What do people think is happening here? Is hostname implicitly added in the first command (to match what was given in the `SELECT` error) so I can rule out hostname issue?

Comment: The hostname is implicitly added, but `select * from mysql.user` to verify that you don't have multiple users with the same username.  The `@'%'` user won't be used if there is a more specific one.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thank you. I checked, it only has one that matched the user I was trying to select as :/

Comment: And the only user you found with that username has `host = '%'`?  It isn't clear what "matched the user" means, here.

Comment: I note that your user only has `SELECT` on "mydb" and "anotherdb".  The only plausible scenario I can think of is that if "mytable" is actually a view and has `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` in the definition, and "my_column" is actually from a table in a different database, then the invoker (myuser) needs permission to select from there, as well.  Or you manipulated the grant tables manually without a subsequent `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`, though this seems unlikely.

Comment: Thanks. We figured out at work. It was a silly mistake connecting to a different db session in the code. But your anslysis makes very much sense! Thank you.